# Best way for two apps to share data

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

EDIT:
App1 and App2 are web based systems.

So I have two applications, the one is an auth system, think SSO, payments, affiliate earnings and the other is a game plugged into the auth system.

App 1 = SSO & Payments
App 2 = Game

Affiliates log into App 1 to create their affiliate identities and then they point users to App 2 using the unique affiliate code. Their customers play the game and the data is recorded on app 2.

Now what I want is an affiliate to log into app 1 and be able to quickly see all his earnings on app 2.

Methods considered:

1. App 2 has an api accessed by App 1: http://app2/get/earnings/uniquecode when an affiliate wants to view transactions, the page connects to the API which pulls all the data and shows on his or her page.
2. Alternatively, each time a transaction takes place on App 2, it posts this to an api on App 1 which stores it to a table. This means App 1 only needs to access a local db...

Are there other methods that could be considered?

Comment: Surely your earnings are stored somewhere outside of an "app", right? Is there a reason App1 would not be able to access the same data-store that App2 stores earnings data in?

Comment: App as in a web based application (not a mobile app). App1 is a central app, App2..n are apps that authenticate with App1. So App2..n each manage their own transactions which need to be communicated to App1 in one form or other.